# react-localize-redux cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to load translations from a JSON file with react-localize-redux and I keep getting this error. This is all fairly new to me so I apologise if it is something obvious. As fair as I can tell from reading documentation this "should" work?

The error message I am receiving: [image: error]

**translate.js**

```
import { combineReducers, createStore } from 'redux'
import { localizeReducer, initialize, addTranslationForLanguage, getTranslate } from 'react-localize-redux'
import translationsEn from '../../../nls/en.json'

const localeStore = createStore(combineReducers({
  locale: localizeReducer
}))

const languages = ['en']
localeStore.dispatch(initialize(languages))
localeStore.dispatch(addTranslationForLanguage(translationsEn, 'en'))

export default getTranslate(localeStore.getState().locale)
```

**and in my component:**

```
import translate from '../state/translate/translate'

...

<span className='node-output-schema__title'>{translate('outputSchema.title')}</span>
```

Any ideas to what might be going wrong?

Comment: may be { translate(['outputSchema.title']) }, not sure though

Comment: what's there in your localize.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems like you mixed some different frameworks inside here.

The localisation package is called - react-localize-redux.
But inside your error logs I can see that you are using some angular.

Also I just checked the documentation from the react-localize-redux package and it seems like you are working with an outdated version.
For me it should be enough to just provide a Provider to your app and afterwards use the higher order component (import { withLocalize } from "react-localize-redux";
)

Also I would recommend to use this package, which is a lot easier to handle (and indeed I used it for a project myselft) 
react-18next (https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next)

Answer (score 0):

this error rases because your property is undefined, so check your error and get the exact line(you can find the error on the console tab of your browser) and check which property used there and check where you filled that property if you didn't fill your property then set it